# Passing variables as arguments to networkx.add_edge() attributes

Tags: python, networkx

I'm trying to write the following piece of code in python.

```
g = networkx.Digraph()
g.add_edge(1,2,x = 2)
```

The 'x' here is a variable. But networkx seems to take this as a name of the attribute. I need to pass what's inside x as the name of the attribute. How do I do it?

Comment: What *is* inside x? You define it on a previous line?

Comment: Also: `networkx` uses key-value pairs for the attributes for each edge. If you want `x` to be the value, what do you want to be the key?

Comment: x has the name of some other node; some string basically.

Comment: I want x to be the key in the dict

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`add_edge`](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.DiGraph.add_edge.html) takes a `dict` for attributes. You just need to put the attribute/value pairs in a `dict`:

```
g.add_edge(1, 2, {x:2})
# or more explicitly
g.add_edge(1, 2, attr_dict={x:2})
```

Example:

```
In [25]: g = networkx.DiGraph()

In [26]: x = 'some string'

In [27]: g.add_edge(1, 2, {x:2})

In [28]: g[1][2]
Out[28]: {'some string': 2}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
g = networkx.Digraph()
g.add_edge(1, 2, **{x: 2})
```

See [how to use *args and **kwargs in Python](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/). Alternatively, `networkx` also allows you to give it directly as a dictionary:

```
g.add_edge(1, 2, {x: 2})
```